# How to invite a colleague to do a casual activity with you using proper language?

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-structure, politeness

I would like to make friends at work as I am a migrant and am pretty much isolated from the society.

What I am not sure about is how to invite someone (a colleague I mean) to do a casual activity with me and not sound impolite/pushy/unprofessional/needy. Also I am a girl and he is a guy. Don't want to sound flirty as well.

For instance, I have a colleague who seems to be into playing games such as chess, etc.

If I tell him something like this, would it be appropriate?

> Hello, hello. If I remember correctly, you like playing chess. My
>   partner and I are not pros but like to play chess and other types of
>   games as well.  We thought maybe we could arrange a little game
>   night/day if you are interested at all?

Would appreciate any advice as to how make these sentences in such a way to serve my purpose.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: We can probably advise you how to extend the invitation *politely* -- but how to do it without *any* connotation of romantic interest?  I think that's next to impossible in *any* language, because it has more to do with your relationship and his level of interest in you, than the words you choose.  Even your very nice example *could* be construed as a romantic overture, if he wanted to see it that way.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your comment. On a side note, the fact that we are both in committed relationships and the fact that I mention my partner in the invitation, will that decrease the chance of him interpreting it as a romantic invitation? All I am looking for is making good friends...

Comment: Maryam, I expect your instinct is as good as mine.  This is about *personality* and not language, and would likely be no different anywhere else in the world.

Comment: yeah, I see your point :)

Comment: They do say "Love is the universal language".   But yeah, if you ask my personal *gjuess* I'd say you're fine -- however, is this in the UK?  There may be cultural cues you can include to help clarify your invitation, but we'd have to get a native British perspective.  :)

Comment: You're right... culture is an important factor here .It is actually in Australia. Although, the guy is Russian raised in Australia :)

Comment: Ah.  Shame, we rarely see Aussies on this site.  Who knows, we might get lucky.

Comment: "**Hi. Wish to join me and my partner in a game of chess? I heard that you like playing it. How about it?**" - how's this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make some moves on your colleague (chess moves, that is) you could ask:

> Are you **up for** playing some chess this weekend?
>   My {boyfriend|partner|etc} and I are trying to set up a chess
>   day.